# Gson cannot find parameter name

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to encode a json using Gson in Android Studio.

The name of parameters in the generated string is different of the original class

this is the class to encode:

```
public class Teste {
    boolean vivo;

    public boolean isVivo() {
        return vivo;
    }

    public void setVivo(boolean vivo) {
        this.vivo = vivo;
    }

    String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

This is the way I'm using gson

```
public static String getMensagem() {

    Teste teste = new Teste();
    teste.setNome("Messias");

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    String json =gson.toJson(teste);

    Log.e("json gerado: ", json);
    return json;
}
```

And finally the generated json

```
{"a":"Messias"}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine, the problem is elsewhere. What version of Gson are you using? You are not setting any specific configuration to the Gson object?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?  Looks like it might have obfuscated your variable names.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html